# Pyautogui click() and moveTo() not working mac os bigsur

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've been trying to use the pyautogui library but when i try to use the move() the python launcher bounces on the dock then disappears and nothing happens, i don't even get any errors, I saw a post from a while back when catalina was around and the person who made the post ended up going back to an older OS X because they couldn't figure out a solution, i also found the problem on the github repo for pyautogui but the solution which was to add your terminal or python launcher or code editor to accessibility list in privacy didn't work for me. Below i'm providing my code, the github issue link and the other person's post, by the way i've done everything they said they've done. I'd really appreciate some help, thanks.

> Is anyone else having PyAutoGUI issues after updating to Catalina?
> pyautogui.click() almost seems to work. Clicks work in the window that
> I tell it to, but it's as if immediately after a click, the window
> focus returns to VS Code or Terminal. And then any
> pyautogui.typewrite, keyup, keydown, any of those keystroke commands
> are entered into VS Code or Terminal rather than the window I've had
> it click on to focus. Doing a command + tab doesn't do the trick
> either as those keys are entered into Terminal rather than acting as
> hotkeys on OSX. I can't seem to keep the focus on the window I'm
> trying to operate on. I've tried reverting from zsh back to bash. I've
> tried adding Terminal, zsh, bash, and VS Code in the Accessibility
> area of Security & Settings to give full keyboard and mouse control.
> Apple does say that their depreciating Quartz (what pyautogui is built
> off of to operate OSX) in 10.15 (realized this one too little, too
> late). But that's supposed to mean it still works they just won't be
> updating it, right? Anyone else experiencing this? I'm hoping for
> someone smarter than me who can guide me to a fix. Thanks!

```
import os, sys, subprocess
import pyautogui 
import time

def open_file(filename):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.startfile(filename)
    else:
        opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
        subprocess.call([opener, filename])

def runZoom():
     open_file("/Applications/zoom.us.app")
     joinbtn=pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("Join_Meeting.png", confidence=.5)
     pyautogui.moveTo(joinbtn)
     pyautogui.click()

runZoom()
```

Github issue link:https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/247

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PyDirectInput module.

`pip install pydirectinput`

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble until I enabled access to accessibility features, thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32259594)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue on my mac, you have to manually add Python Launcher to the list of apps that can control your computer.

System preferences --> Security & Privacy --> Accessibilty --> +Python Launcher

i also added terminal to the list.